# BSON compatible HTTP request library for C

Tags: c, json, http, asp.net-web-api, bson

I am making a C application on a Raspberry Pi that receives data, and then packages into BSON and sends it to a asp.net web API using HTTP post. So far i've been using the Libcurl (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) library for creating and sending the HTTP requests and Libbson (http://api.mongodb.org/libbson/1.1.4/) for creating the BSON objects.

However i have been unable to make the two libraries work together. I can convert the BSON to JSON and send it just fine. But i cannot figure out how to send the data in a BSON format.

So im hoping that either somebody knows a trick for converting the BSON data into some kind of string that can stil be read as BSON on the web API side, or know of some other HTTP request library for C that is compatible with BSON.

The application is for an internship/school assignment, where the company im interning at, would prefer BSON in order to make the HTTP packages as small as possible to save bandwidth. However i am unsure how big the packages need to be for BSON to actually be smalled than JSON, so if anybody has any expert knowledge on that subject it would alos be nice. Since it might prove that i should be using JSON instead.

Comment: MongoDB uses BSON as a protocol and there is also a driver for C. Maybe it also contains some conversion you could probably make use of. Thought that could help or probably give you more information about BSON in general.

Comment: @Matthias Thanks i tried looking into that, but im trying to avoid using any MongoDB at all. And as far as i have been able to tell the purpose of the Libbson library, is to be able to use the BSON format without it being related to MongoDB

Comment: You should probably post some code of whats not working between your two libs